# How to verify a wikipedia post?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

I shared a link to one of my answers but OP told that answer cannot be accepted as link is not valid, so how can i verify that Wikipedia link?

This is the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunti) in question, and the answer is [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2311/75).

Comment: I cannot answer your question unless you share the link of your answer as well..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we add a citation banner for answers that rely solely on Wikipedia?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/can-we-add-a-citation-banner-for-answers-that-rely-solely-on-wikipedia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not saying whether your answer is right or wrong, am sticking to your question which is **How to verify a wikipedia post?**

I read [your answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2311/124), [the discussion between you and other user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15912/discussion-between-awal-garg-and-sid-m) and also the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunti). Now, other user in the discussion room said that

> we don't accept answers entirely based on wiki w/o other backings....

The statement is true, but in a way that if a user is quoting entire answer from Wikipedia.

We encourage users to write the answers on their own and you did that. As far as the referencing goes, sharing Wikipedia links are fine, but to make your answer even better, try sharing links to scriptures from authentic web sources.

Refer answers of **some** professionals and see how they draft their answers, for example - [Jabahar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/38/jabahar), [Keshav](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan), [Bharat](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/14/bharat) etc...

---

So inshort, Wikipedia links are fine, the user didn't accepted your link because he didn't find any valid reference for his question.

Comment: okies got it, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is not actually about verifying a wikipedia link. There are many sources on Internet which do provide false information. To make sure whether your claim is true, have atleast two or more different sources which does strengths your claim. This is good if you are not well aware of the story or incident.

BTW, having just single source like wiki is also good if you are well aware of the story or incident. (*remember to include the content as citation in your post*)