# Does anyone who got a temple, will make them god/goddesses by default and their questions would be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, close-reasons

We just got [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28670/who-is-the-goddess-depicted-as-bharat-mata-why-is-she-having-indian-tricolor) which got debated a lot for on-topicness and one of the answerers made argument that it's on-topic because “Bharat Mata" has a temple and  make it on topic because Wikipedia says so:

> If she is not a Hindu goddess, then that can be an answer. One may write as "There is no goddess as Bharat-mata". However you may see my answer, which is taken from **wiki and says that she is a Hiundu goddess** and **also has a temple in Benaras**. In either way, if she is a goddess or not, the question is answerable from Hinduism context. Because **her attire matches many other devi-s**. Whether other devi-devata-s are on-topic or not is a separate discussion. But "Bharat-mata" among them is too important figure culturally to be trivialised.

We discussed about Wikipedia and its credibility before too:

- [Is it OK to cite Wikipedia in answers?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/151/76)
- [How to verify a wikipedia post?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/76)

This question also got close vote from one of the current moderator too but one of the answerer, OP and other reopened it again.

Rajinikanth has temple, [Sachin Tendulkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachin_Tendulkar) also [has one](https://www.hindustantimes.com/india/a-temple-for-god-of-cricket-sachin-tendulkar-in-bihar/story-ETQfMpSOLsrPb1eSZdv8ZM.html) and Prime Minister of India [Narendra Modi temple](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/a-temple-for-modi-to-be-built-in-meerut/article19786541.ece) is also coming. And it might sound more surprising one Indian prays to Donald Trump also.

So are they all on topic on this site?

<sub>**Note: And kindly don't bring nationalism here, as it is Hinduism site and we should not restrict it to one country only.**</sub>

Comment: Hinduism != Nationalism. Better cast  delete vote on questions as such.

Comment: Wikipedia related stuff doesn't really add anything to the question. Those were removed by me in the last revision. Do you think, "person with temple become god" and "citing source from wikipedia" are related in any way?

Comment: Whoever voted to close question, don't abuse your privilege. The target selected is using Wikipedia in answers. This is about site scope. There is a lot of difference between the two. Don't use privilege as you like. There are penalties and suspensions if it's abused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it OK to cite Wikipedia in answers?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/is-it-ok-to-cite-wikipedia-in-answers)

Answer (score 2):

**No**. Anyone with a temple, doesn't make them Hindu God/Goddess.
If someone starts a question on Rajinikanth, Sachin Tendulkar, Narendra Modi then the question can be closed by the community members. Because they are real people with no verifiable godly status.

Most likely such question will be deleted by community or mods if they are found single bit of trolling.

I also explained you [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46241514#46241514), why we can't have scriptural references for many figures like "Bharata mata".

Comment: Why have u responded on whether Wiki is a valid source or not in this answer? If that was the question here then can we not close the original as a duplicate? Also isn't the question asking two completely unrelated questions in one? I guess the downvotes u got are because of the part that's on Wiki. @iammilind

Comment: Also regarding the Main question, people will never ask if Rajnikant is a god of Hinduism or not unless the intention of the user is bad (something like trolling). @iammilind  So, the question is discussing something that is never gong to happen.

Comment: @Rickross, it will not make it duplicate, because it's not entirely asking about it. The OP himself has flagged to Mod to pick the right version. So let's see if they find Wiki related stuff helpful to this post or not.